# join entre 2 tablas en 2 bases de datos distintas en un mismo servidor

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access

Buenos días: Necesito hacer varios join entre varias tablas en 2 bases de datos distintas que se encuentran en un mismo servidor.
He googleado pero las soluciones que he encontrado no me funcionan, la mayoría utilizan "dbo" el cual me da un error cuando ejecuto la sentencia y las otras son para bases de datos de Oracle o SQLServer o con Laravel.

Este es uno de los códigos que he utilizado:

```
SELECT tab2.column_name
FROM  [DB1.mdf].[dbo].[table_name_1] tab1 
INNER JOIN [DB2.mdf].[dbo].[table_name_2]  tab2   
       ON tab1.col_name = tab2.col_name
```

Dejo la imagen de las tablas y sus relaciones, mucho agradecería la ayuda que me puedan dar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega algo de lo que hayas intentado port favor

Comment: ¿Seguro que esto es MySQL?

Comment: Hola BetaM, gracias por responder. No es mysql, es una imagen de la consulta hecha pero en Access, ahí coloqué las tablas juntas para poder tener una idea de cómo hacer el join, la coloco como referencia de cómo necesito hacer el join.

Comment: Con la información que pude conseguir en internet intenté anteponiendo a cada tabla el nombre de la bd e intercalando el término "dbo" (como lo dicen en la mayoría de los foros) pero no lo reconoce.

Comment: Prueba a vincular las tablas de esas bases a tu base, para luego hacer la consulta. Échale un ojo a [Vincular a datos en otra base de datos de Access](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/importar-o-vincular-a-los-datos-de-otra-base-de-datos-de-access-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6?ui=es-es&rs=es-es&ad=es#linkdata)

Answer (score 1):

Debería funcionarte sin problema usando `dbo` en caso de no haber cambiado el esquema por defecto. Intenta con '`..`', por si tu esquema es otro:

```
SELECT eventos.*, agencias.* 
FROM nombreBD1..eventos INNER JOIN nombreBD2..agencias_bancarias as agencias
ON eventos.id_agencia = agencias.id_agencia
```

Podrías intentar colocando la ruta completa del fichero de la otra BD.

```
SELECT eventos.*, agencias.* 
FROM eventos INNER JOIN [;database=C:\Ruta\Hacia\SegundaBDaccdb.accdb'].[agencias_bancarias] as agencias
ON eventos.id_agencia = agencias.id_agencia
```